# Zend query for temp table

Tags: php, zend-framework

this is my query where i am getting weekly and total views

```
select count(ms.test_public_id) as total_views, ms1.recent_views from test_stats ms 
join (select count(test_stats.test_public_id) as recent_views from test_stats 
where test_stats.test_public_id = '$tourid' 
and test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) ms1 
where ms.test_public_id ='$tourid'
```

I have tried to implement in zend the output is like this

```
$cols = array ('count(ms.test_public_id) as total_views', 'ms1.recent_views', 'count(test_stats.test_public_id) as recent_views' );
$select = $db ->select () 
->from ( 'test', $cols )
->join ( 'user', 'user.user_id = test.user_id', array () )
->join ( 'test_stats', 'test_stats.test_public_id =test.test_public_id', array ())
->where ( 'test_stats.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' ) 
->where ( 'test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' ) 
->where ( 'ms.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' ) 
->group ( 'test_stats.test_public_id' )
->order ( 'title' );
$result = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
```

Please correct me where i am doing wrong..........

Answer (score 0):

`->join ( 'user', 'user.user_id = test.user_id', array () );` why the empty array? and **title** is ambigous in **order** I think....try **echo $select=**.... to see what query is executed and compare with what you want.

TRY

```
    $cols = array ('count(ms.test_public_id) as total_views', 'ms1.recent_views', 'count(test_stats.test_public_id) as recent_views' );
  echo  $select = $db ->select () 
    ->from ( 'test', $cols )
    ->join ( 'user', 'user.user_id = test.user_id', array () )
    ->join ( 'test_stats', 'test_stats.test_public_id =test.test_public_id', array ())
    ->where ( 'test_stats.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' ) 
    ->where ( 'test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' ) 
    ->where ( 'ms.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' ) 
    ->group ( 'test_stats.test_public_id' )
    ->order ( 'test.title' );
    $result = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
```

Comment: change ->where ( 'ms.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' ) 'ms' to you`re correct table name...I am only guessing ->where ( 'test_stats.test_public_id = ?', '$testId' )

Comment: In sql query there is ms and ms1 are there i don't what to with those queries i wrote blindly zend query (As i don't know much about zend db) by seeing another solution..................